# Browser not firing drop event

Tags: javascript, dojo, coffeescript

I have simple page wrapper div with ID "wrapper". Using Dojo/on I have connected events "dragover" and "drop".

```
// onevent is dojo/on
onevent query("#body"), "dragover", (e) =>
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log "Page HTML drag over start"

onevent query("#body"), "drop", (e) =>
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log e
```

Dragover is firing correctly, but drop isnt (browser [Chrome/Safari Mac] open dropped file).

Where can be problem please?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean to say "I have simple page wrapper div with ID "body""?